# Why is $(x-1)(y+2)=4$ an example of a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Solving a question on whether $(x-1)(y+2)=4$ is an equation of a circle, ellipse, hyperbola or a stright line. My teacher said that it is an example of an equation of circle. However, drawing this equation it seems to me that this equation  looks nothing like a circle but more like a hyperbola.

Comment: It is indeed *not* a circle. Its easily rearranged to $y=4/(x-1) - 2$ which is a hyperbola (with vertical and horizontal asymptote). Alternatively, an easy change of coordinates gets you to $XY=4$ which is one of the forms for a hyperbola

Comment: $xy=b$, where $b$ is known. It is not a circle, it is hyperbola. $x^2+y^2=b$ is a circle

Comment: One quick way to see that it is not a circle is to note that $x$ (or $y$) is not bounded.  We can make either variable as large or as small as we like.

Comment: circles are represented as $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$ where radius of circle is $r$ and its center is at $(a,b)$. Obviously this equation is not circle. For this example, let $x' = x-1$ and $y' = y+2$, then $x'y'=4$ with graph shifted 1 to left and 2 to up and this is hyperbola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equation for a circle is $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 = r^2$, where the center of the circle is $(a, b)$ and the radius is $r$. If we try to rearrange the equation that you have, and try to make it into the equation of a circle, we can see that it is not an example of a circle. Let's try to turn $(x - 1)(y + 2) = 4$ into an equation for a circle.

Expanding $(x - 1)(y - 2) = 4$, we get:

$xy - 2x - y + 2 = 4$.

$xy - 2x - y - 2 = 0.$

But, we have no $x^2$ or $y^2$ term in the equation, so this can't be the equation for a circle. (This is because $(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2$ would give an $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms if you expanded it.)

So, this equation is not a circle. But, it is something called a [hyperbola](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/waymakercollegealgebra/chapter/equations-of-hyperbolas/#:%7E:text=Like%20hyperbolas%20centered%20at%20the,%3D%20a%202%20%2B%20b%202%20.). This equation is a hyperbola due to what Calvin Khor said in the comments;  you can get $y$ in terms of $x$:

$y = \frac{4}{x - 1} - 2$, which is the equation of a hyperbola.